# Debian Buster connecting via HTTPS to IPs

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, debian-buster

Here is my situation:

I have a current Debian Buster installation (10.2).
I have a basic setup, no special services or configurations within the OS.
There is a Gitlab Omnibus instance on top of the OS but I am quite sure the IP in question is not related to that.
For all mayor components (git, wget, apt, etc.) I have a proxy configured.

The server tries to connect to the following IPs directly roughly every hour: `23.111.9.35`. The IP seems to be related to some Debian security service, but I can not find any information on an automation that would do this. The `reportbug` tools does not seem to be it.

Has anyone any idea what this could be exactly?

Comment: What hostname do you see in the TLS handshake's SNI field?

Comment: DNS Name: *.netdna-ssl.com
DNS Name: netdna-ssl.com

Comment: So, check your logs to see what runs every hour. Because my Debian system doesn’t have anything in the hourly cron or systemd timers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have [unattended-upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) running. Maybe in the host OS, but you didn't specify how you have gitlab installed so it's possible if it's in docker that they run `unattended-upgrades`.

Comment: Hi Josef and welcome to the community!
Sadly that is not it, the unattended-upgrades package is not even installed. Also normal updating works, as all APT traffic goes through our Proxy server.